# PostgreSQL - Finding highest column value

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql

Let's say I had a table that tracked test scores for students.

```
CREATE TABLE scores (
student_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(100),
test1 INTEGER,
test2 INTEGER,
test3 INTEGER,
test4 INTEGER,
highest_score VARCHAR(50)
)
```

If I wanted the highest_score column to list the test# with the highest score (for example, if the scores were test1: 90, test2: 95, test3: 85, test4: 90, then highest_score would list test2), how could I calculate this? Can this all be done on just PostgreSQL? Or would I need to calculate this on the back end and send the result back to the table?

I'm using React on my front end, and Node on my backend.

Comment: Because a database is optimized for data retrieve, you can make this in backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `case` expression:

```sql
update scores
set highest_score = case 
    when test1 = greatest(test1, test2, test3, test4) then 'test1'
    when test2 = greatest(test1, test2, test3, test4) then 'test2'
    when test3 = greatest(test1, test2, test3, test4) then 'test3'
    else 'test4'
end
```

The function [`greatest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST) was introduced in Postgres 8.1.

Comment: I tried this, and received this response:

"Error: no such function: greatest"

Comment: max usually do the wrong thing, what postgres version?